# Create HTML table using multilevel JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I am using jquery with HTML and I need to do a table HTML using JSON data.

It would be simple if JSON didn't have multilevels and I need to make the resource flexible to support any JSON.

I've seen some examples using lists, but in my case I only need to use objects

Examples:

JSON Data:

```
{
        "A":
        {
            "B":
            {
            "B1":"B1-a",
            "B2": "B2-a"
            },
            "C":
            {
            "Ca":"Cb"
            }
        },
        "D":
        {
            "E":
            {
            "E1":"E1-a",
            "E2":"E2-a"
            },
            "F":
            {
            "Fa":"Fb"
            }
        }
    }
```

Table HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody id="JSONTable">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1-a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B2-a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>Ca</td>
        <td>Cb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E1</td>
        <td>E1-a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E2</td>
        <td>E2-a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Fa</td>
        <td>Fb</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hey, Please provide a sample of data you want to work with.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your expected output?

Comment: Ultimately, it's going to have to boil down to lists. You have to make a list of keys and their values from the objects you have in order to iterate over them to make the rows and columns you want. I suggest looking into [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)